# Triangulation Tutorials for Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation, triangulation

I have make the application of GPS which give me the Latitude and Longitude of current location, but the problem is that in some particular areas GPS doesn't provide the location. Can any one suggest me the tutorials of triangulation technique based on cell signals or wifi signals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an Android smartphone is unable to get a GPS fix, it can still likely determine its position using either cell tower location or WiFi positioning. Neither are as accurate, but they don't require a clear view of the sky. Here are some details on how to access and compare all three of these positioning methods: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#BestPerformance

I'm not sure what it is that you're hoping to triangulate based on. WiFi signals? Here's [an SO question about triangulating based on cell signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026625/implementing-triangulation-in-android).

Technically speaking, GPS uses [trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration), because it's based on distance measures rather than angular measures.

Comment: I have edited my question, any technique which give me the current location without using GPS...

Comment: So does this technique of getting lat/lon from cell-id happen from the SDK's side? As in, no need to hit OpenCellID dbs or anything?

Comment: @Reddox: Yes, the SDK takes care of all the necessary steps. Whether the position information is ultimately sourced from the cell tower itself, a separate carrier service, a Google service, or a third-party service... that's a question I can't answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the link Drew provided you would see that there is no need to do your own triangualtion, Android will do triangulation on wifi and cell towers for you. Although it is recommened to flow the logic described in the link Drew provided, you specifically get this type of location use the [NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) instead of the [GPS_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER).